# How to use environment variable in Dockerfile RUN

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I've read several tutorials about this and it seems like this code should work.  I want to use `RUN` in my Dockerfile to write environment variables to a config file.  The Dockerfile is simply:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
RUN echo "I am ${USERNAME}" > /home/dockerfile.log
```

I am starting it with this docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - USERNAME=larry
```

After starting with `docker-compose up -d` the log file just says *I Am* so the environment variable is empty.  What's wrong here?  If I run `docker-compose config` I can see the variable shown correctly there.

Answer (score 0):

The Run command is executed at build time (I.e. when building the image ) while the environment variable in your docker-compose is added to the container at run time. So when the Run command is executed the environment variable has not been populated yet. If you want to pass a parameter at build time, I would suggest using a build argument instead. In your compose file use arg instead of environment